# Why can't i use the € symbol with printf?

Tags: c, symbols

How can i put this symbol (€) on the terminal using c.
I've tried:

printf("%c",0128);

0128 is the code on the ascii table but the compiller gives the error:

invalid digit 8 in octal constant

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: invalid digit "8" in octal constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280028/error-invalid-digit-8-in-octal-constant)

Comment: `0128` is octal, but illegal.

Comment: but if i can't use the 0 before the other numbers because is considered octal how do i print €

Comment: There is no ASCII code for €. You are looking at some other encoding than ASCII.  Unicode is U20AC

Comment: See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 It has a specific example for (€)

Comment: If you change from 0128 to 128 it will work on a terminal set for cp1252 (typical ANSI Windows code page)

Comment: Try UTF8: `char sz[4] = {0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC, 0}; printf("%s\n", sz);`

Comment: If the C compiler's source character set and execution character set are both UTF-8 and the terminal's character encoding is UTF-8, it may be as simple as `printf("€");`, but it depends what assumptions you are willing to make.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric literals that begin with `0` like that, are interpreted as octal (base 8) and therefore comprised solely of digits from `0`-`7`.  So `08` is illegal, and so is `0128`.

[Windows-1252 (CP-1252)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout) encoding of the euro sign `€` is decimal `128`.

What you have posted an image of is the [Alt code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) which is a way of entering the character on Windows by typing: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> on the numeric key pad.

You may be able to fix your problem by removing the leading zero (to produce the decimal literal `128`), provided you are using CP-1252.

Comment: If this doesn't help, then you need to disclose the actual code page (encoding) of the terminal you are using.  You can find your code page by entering `chcp` on the command line.  If it's 850 (which is common), then you're out of luck - there is no encoding of the `€` symbol in [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).

Comment: A console is not very likely to be be cp1252. In the US, cp437 is far more likely, and [it doesn't have "€"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a few things here.

First, the table of which you posted a fragment does not show character codes. It apparently documents how to enter characters on Windows (I covered this in a reply to another question here: [C# Mapping ALT+<XXX> codes to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058602/c-sharp-mapping-altxxx-codes-to-characters/37059677#37059677)). The leading zero here means that the character code you're entering refers to the so-called ANSI codepage instead of OEM one.

Note that the character you get by typing Alt+0128 may vary from computer to computer.

Also note that 128 is not an ASCII code. [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only covers character codes 0 to 127.

Second, leading zero in an integer literal in C and its successors has a different meaning. It means that the number is written in the [octal numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#In_computers). Octal notation was more popular than hexadecimal back in 70s when C was drafted. By definition, 8 is not a valid octal digit, so `0128` is a lexical error.

These two meanings are unrelated. So, if you want to print a character that is entered by the key combination Alt+0128, you need to do that otherwise.

Also note that in many cases you cannot have `€` expressed as one `char` unit. If your console is configured to UTF-8, then the Unicode codepoint for it, 0x20AC, is represented by three bytes: 0xe2, 0x82, 0xac (or 226, 130, 172).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to print stuff like that is... *don’t use hex/oct/whatever constants*, ***use a string***.

Use your text editor’s ability to save source code as UTF-8 and do that directly:

```
puts( "Dinner is €12.50." );
```

Assuming:

- Compiler takes UTF-8 source input (modern compilers do, older compilers might require a flag)
- The standard library handles UTF-8 (it better these days)
- A terminal that can display UTF-8

That last one is the sticking point. Most modern systems work over UTF-8 display, but the old Windows Console is still in use in a lot of places, and that requires a little extra help. Make sure to have it working in UTF-8 output mode (`chcp 65001` on the command-line or the equivalent in code using `SetConsoleOutputCP`).